# Delete item in calendar after 3 days with approval status is pending - SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-calendar

I need the calendar to automatically delete an item after created 3 days with its approval status is still pending. I could do delete after 3 days with information policy management, however, i cannot find the option for another field. I tried with sharepoint designer's workflow, but i didn't know how to compare the created field against the concrete value.

Comment: store your concrete value in in a local variable of your workflow and compare it

Answer (score 0):

[image: workflow]

you can try it this way using workflow. In this case your WF should run daily

OR

you can pause the WF for 3 days

[image: Workflow with pause]